# plotting pdf of Gaussian distribution with bayespy

Tags: python, bayesian-networks

I tried to run the following script of bayespy.

```
#n = GaussianARD(0, 1e-6); # ok
n = Gaussian([0],[[1]]);# ng
bpplt.pdf(n, np.linspace(-10, 20, num=100));
bpplt.pyplot.show();
```

Then I've got the following error.

```
  File "./bayespytest.py", line 134, in <module>
    bpplt.pdf(n, np.linspace(-10, 20, num=100));
  File "C:\home\bin\python3_32\lib\site-packages\bayespy-0.5.6-py3.5.egg\bayespy\plot.py", line 195, in pdf
    retval = axes.plot(x, p, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\home\bin\python3_32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1819, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\home\bin\python3_32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 1382, in plot
    for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):
  File "C:\home\bin\python3_32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 381, in _grab_next_args
    for seg in self._plot_args(remaining, kwargs):
  File "C:\home\bin\python3_32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 359, in _plot_args
    x, y = self._xy_from_xy(x, y)
  File "C:\home\bin\python3_32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 219, in _xy_from_xy
    raise ValueError("x and y must have same first dimension")
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension
```

I don't get the error when I use GaussianARD instead.
How can I remove the error and plot pdf of Gaussian?

Thanks.

Comment: What is len(n)?

Comment: TypeError: object of type 'Gaussian' has no len()

Comment: You probably have to evaluate y values using the `Gaussian` object returned. For example, you cannot just plot `plt.plot(np.sin, np.linspace(-10, 20, num=100))`